# Error message ”sorry: constant selects in always_* processes are not currently supported (all bits will be included).“ in SystemVerilog

Tags: case, system-verilog

I need to use "case" statement to implement a 4-bit priority encoder,and the code is showed below:

```
module case2(
    input [3 : 0] in,
    output logic [1 : 0] pos
);
    always_comb begin
        case(1)
            in[0]:pos=2'b00;
            in[1]:pos=2'b01;
            in[2]:pos=2'b10;
            in[3]:pos=2'b11;
            default:pos=2'b00;
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

It seems that I can't use '1' as a expr of case in the always_comb block.I have searched in google,but nothing helpful is acquired.How can I solve this problem?Is constant can not be used as a expr of case?I think it's unreasonable.
Thanks for your advice!

Comment: What simulator/synthesizer/etc. are you using? Also note that you probably what to use `case(1'b1)`.

Comment: Most likely it is Icarus Verilog. It's support for System Verilog isn't complete yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Not currently supported*" means the tool believes the code is valid, but they have not implemented it yet. You did not say what tool you are using.

There is always the brute force approach:

```
always_comb 
        case(in)
        4'b0001,4'b0011, ...     4'b1111 :pos=2'b00;
        4'b0010,4'b0110, 4'b1010,4'b1110 :pos=2'b01;
        4'b0100,4'b1100                  :pos=2'b10;
        4'b1000                          :pos=2'b11;
        default                          :pos=2'b00;
endcase
```

Another way you can write this is with a `priority if` statement

```
always_comb
  priority if (in[0]) pos=2'b00;
      else if (in[1]) pos=2'b01;
      else if (in[2]) pos=2'b10;
      else if (in[3]) pos=2'b11;
      else            pos=2'b00;
```

Comment: I use a online judge platform.The platform ordered me to use `case` to finish the task.Do you have any further advice?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `casez`?

Comment: no,`casez` is for following task.

Comment: I‘m sorry that the standard answer is the brute force approach，maybe for a green hand it’s the most situable thinking.

Comment: I guess some instructors feel they need to teach you the pain of one situation to appreciate the benefit of another feature.